# Is there any way to get Ediff to not open its navigation interface in an external window?

Tags: emacs

Not being using Emacs all that long (v23, windows) and just discovered <kbd>M-x ediff</kbd>. Fantastic.
Although I'm not to keen on the fact it opens its help/navigation in a separate frame/window, meaning that if I lose focus to that window, the single key shortcuts don't work.

For example as soon as I press <kbd>?</kbd> to expand the window, it shifts over top of my current window, so I have to pick up my mouse and move it to another screen. Then if I lose focus to that window and press <kbd>p</kbd> / <kbd>n</kbd> / <kbd>j</kbd> or any other key to work with the diff, it inserts it into my document. So i have to undo, grab mouse, focus to other window, and repeat.

Is there any way to configure these options to show in a split instead?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm being impatient and asked this question a bit too early. If the window isn't expanded and remains in its initial state in the top right corner of the screen, it really isn't all that obtrusive at all.

Comment: Agreed - it's not that bad.  Also hit '?' again and it shrinks back.  And welcome to Emacs.  Being facile with it has been a money-maker for me over the years.

Answer (score 33):

I didn't know how to do it but it is usually easy to learn with Emacs.  First I asked about ediff customizations:

```
M-x customize-apropos
ediff
```

I saw there is something called **Ediff Window Setup Function** which takes the values **Multi Frame**, **Single Frame**, or **Other Function**.   Mine was set to **Multi Frame** and changed it to **Single Frame** and saved it for future sessions.   And *Voila!* as they say somewhere.

Comment: `M-x customize-apropos` didn’t find anything for ediff in Emacs 25.1. `M-x customize-group RET ediff RET` did.

Answer (score 24):

Simply:

```
 (setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

M-x describe-variable ediff-window-setup-function will enlighten you
further.

For reference my ediff customisation is fairly simple:

```
(if (locate-library "ediff")
    (progn
      (autoload 'ediff-files "ediff")
      (autoload 'ediff-buffers "ediff")

       (eval-after-load "ediff" '(progn
              (message "doing ediff customisation")
              (setq diff-switches               "-u"
                ediff-custom-diff-options   "-U3"
                ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally
                ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)

              (add-hook 'ediff-startup-hook 'ediff-toggle-wide-display)
              (add-hook 'ediff-cleanup-hook 'ediff-toggle-wide-display)
              (add-hook 'ediff-suspend-hook 'ediff-toggle-wide-display)))))
```

Answer (score 16):

From chapter *[Window and Frame Configuration](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Window-and-Frame-Configuration.html)* in Ediff User's Manual:

> The following variable controls how
>   windows are set up:
>
> `ediff-window-setup-function`
>
> The multiframe setup is done by the `ediff-setup-windows-multiframe`
>   function, which is the default on
>   windowing displays. The plain setup,
>   one where all windows are always in
>   one frame, is done by
>   `ediff-setup-windows-plain`, which is
>   the default on a non-windowing display
>   (or in an xterm window). In fact,
>   under Emacs, **you can switch freely
>   between these two setups by executing
>   the command `ediff-toggle-multiframe`**
>   using the Minibuffer of the Menubar.

Answer (score 7):

```
(custom-set-variables    
  ...
 '(ediff-window-setup-function (quote ediff-setup-windows-plain))
  ...)
```

Not that you would set the variable this way, but it allows you to know these things:

- The variable you are interested in is `ediff-window-setup-function`
- The value it needs to be set to is `ediff-setup-windows-plain`
- You can configure the variable from customize: `M-x customize-group RET ediff-window`

  Ediff Window Setup Function: Menu Single Frame

Answer (score 4):

Note: you can avoid using the mouse to go back to the ediff control window by using <kbd>M-x other-frame</kbd>.  Also found on <kbd>C-x 5 o</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This no longer works in 2017 gnu emacs (24.5, 25.2, 2017) on windows

```
   (setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain) ; stopped working
```

Even

```
   ediff-toggle-multiframe ; no longer has any effect now.
```

It works in emacs22.3 on windows, so I have use older emacs from 2008!

Comment: `ediff-setup-windows-plain` works fine with Emacs Version 25.1 (9.0) on macOS. Though I am setting it by using `custom-set-variables` dunno if it matters.